# Is there a way to sort a table based on a cell value in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

My current table looks like this:

| Status |
| --- |
| Draft |
| Pending |
| Complete |

I want to sort them based on the value of the cells. Is there a way to do that? I've only been able to sort them using this code:

```
    onChange(status: string){
      const sortState: Sort = {active: status, direction: 'desc'};
      this.sort.active = sortState.active;
      this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
      this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);
    }
```

But I want to sort using the values of the status themselves since I'd want to create a button which when click sorts starting from complete or draft or pending.

Comment: Hey I just gave an answer. Not entirely sure if it's what you're looking for but I hope it sends you down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but I think I understand what you're asking.
You're going to want to convert your values into an array and then use the `.sort()` function. So, assuming you have an array of your cells, we can call that `let array = Cell[]`, you can then access the status of the cells like this:

```
sortCells(){
 let array = Cell[]; // here we're assuming there is already a cell type and a cell.active parameter, like shown in your example.
 let possibleValues = ["Draft","Pending","Complete"]; // easier way to compare two values
 array.sort((a,b)=>{
 let aIndex = possibleValues.indexOf(a.active); // index of gets the location of the element in an array
 let bIndex = possibleValues.indexOf(b.active);

  if(a > b){
   return -1;
  } else if(b > a){
   return 1;
  }else{
   return 0; // they are equal
  }

})
}
```

You can read more about sort here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Hi what if the values are part of MatTableDataSource? Is this code still applicable?